# Setup a 1:0..1 relationship so that nulling the reference automatically deletes the referenced object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

How to setup a `1 : 0..1` relationship with EF 6.x so that setting the navigation property to null also deletes the referenced object automatically?

An example:

```
Student may have 0..1 StudentDetails

var student = new Student();
student.Details = new StudentDetails();
dbContext.Students.Add(student);
...
student.Details = null;
dbContext.SaveChanges(); // should automatically delete the StudentDetails object
```

How to setup the relationship properly? My current attempt is:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
      .HasOptional(x => x.Details)
      .WithRequired();
```

However, that doesn't work :(

Comment: Is this a database first or code first ?

Comment: Code first, fluent configuration

Comment: `dbContext.StudentDetails.Remove(student.Details);`   EF, to my knowledge, doesn't do anything when you set an entity to null.

Comment: I do not want to explicitly do that. There isn't even a `DbSet<StudentDetails>` on my DbContext.

Comment: The setup is correct (you might add `WillCascadeOnDelete()` but that doesn't affect the behavior in question) and works as expected (EF6.1.3). Just make sure the `Details` property is loaded before setting it to `null`. e.g. `var student = dbContext.Students.Include(s => s.Details).First(s => s.Details != null); student.Details = null; dbContext.SaveChanges();` deletes the details record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationship setup is correct and should produce the desired behavior (I would suggest adding `WillCascadeOnDelete()` in order to allow cascade delete which by default is off for one-to-one relationships, but that doesn't affect the behavior in question).

However, the `Details` property must be loaded before setting it to `null` in order to be detected as change by the context change tracker and deleted from the database during `SaveChanges()` call.

You can do that in several ways. For instance, eager load it during the entity retrieval:

```
var student = dbContext.Students
    .Include(s => s.Details) // <--
    .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == ...);
```

or lazy loaded (if lazy loading is enabled) by accessing it:

```
var details = student.Details;
```

or explicit loading it in case you don't know how it's being retrieved and lazy loading is disabled:

```
dbContext.Entry(student).Reference(s => s.Details).Load();
```

Once you do that, the code in question

```
student.Details = null;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

will delete the existing details record from the database.